# REGEX for finding first word of text only

Tags: python, regex

I've got a series of headlines. I want to capture only the first word in the text.

```
for line in messy_info:
    match = re.search(r"^[a-z]{7}",line)
    if match:
        first_word.append(line[:10])
first_word
```

This brings back the first 10 characters, I do not know how to bring back only the first word in this instance.

MY next challenge is to use this first word and print the headline and then underneath the first word.

```
for line in messy_info:
    match = re.search(r"^[a-z]", line)
    if match:
        first_word = line [:100]
        print (first_word)
        splitline = re.split(r"\s[a-z]+\s",word)
        print ("First Word: ",splitline[0])
        print()
    else:
            print("--- not a match ---")
            print()
```

Comment: Please [format code samples](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to get only the matched text in Python?](/q/14936971/90527)", "[Getting text of a Regex match](/q/16217910/90527)"

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the first word:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

input = 'Year jashdjas adsh ajdhjah'

m = re.match(r"\s*\w+", input).group()

print(m)
```

output: Year

the \s* is 0 or more white spaces and \w+ is a word with 1 or more chars

Comment: thanks @ZiTAL I am looking for the first word but all the text isn't a string, its like a huge list of headlines - how would I get the headlines to be a string to then do the function you listed above?

Comment: @Alyce1988 can you write an input example?